# Disable Two-Step Publish Workflow?

Tags: craft3, craft-features

I recently updated to Craft v3.6, which appears to have changed the publishing workflow to require first publishing the draft, then saving the file in order to get back to the entries list. Is there any way to revert to the previous workflow of being able to just press a single button to create a new entry, publish it, and get back to the entries list?

Comment: incredibly annoying feature

Comment: Feels like it could be a setting in the Section or Entry Type. 
A light switch that says "Publish on Save" (When on, draft entries in this section are published immediately on save. When off, entries stay in draft mode until published)
Then just hide the "Publish" button if that setting is set "on".